# jqGrid saveRow with an error function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

This might be a 2 part question.  First one is "what am I doing wrong" and 2nd is "is this the right way?".  Anyway...

I'm attempting to save an edited row with jqgrid and for some reason I've yet to identify, I can't get the error event to fire using [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing).

```
    table.saveRow(rowId,
                  false,
                  false,
                  optionalParams,
                  false,
                  function () { common.ShowMeSomething("error fired"); },
                  false);
```

All ShowMeSomething does is an alert right now, no big deal, but will not fire.  I've went as far as opening up the source, and it's an $.extend with complete: function(res,stat) -- I've attempted to mimic those with a return Json(new { res = "hi", stat = false }) with no luck on it walking down the javascript to fire off the error event.  No luck.

Also, is there a better way to do this?  I need the errors back for validation reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was unclear documentation.  In some of the grids functionality, error == false and success == true which is not the case.  The first parameter is the rowId, the second is a **successful call** to the server (basically, does it exist and did I get an http response) where what I expected is reserved for utter failures that I wasn't able to create.

Moving the function to this second parameter and doing the error handling from the result allows for what I wanted -- simple return Json(whateverObject) and do what needs to be done from there such as reset, show errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't include the code of your jqGrid and the code of MVC controller action which produce the error. So I could only guess what is the reason of your problem.

One reason in the server part could be that you try to return the error as a `Json(...)` and not change the [HTTP response status code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) to an error code. In case of an error you can either set the response code with the code like `HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 500` or use [HttpException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bazc3hww.aspx).

Another possible reason on the client side is that you try to save a row which is not currently edited with respect of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow). The method [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) set additional attribute "editable"="1" for the editing row and [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) save only the row having this attribute.

It you would be include more client and server code in the body of your question one could better help you.